# How can I undo the last cd command on windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to go back to my previous location just like what `cd -` does on most unix shells.

How is this done on windows ?

Comment: see `pushd /?` and `popd /?`

Comment: @elzooilogico this way it will in cmd.exe *not* in powershell (in powershell it produces an error message).  Please see my answer edit for more information.

Comment: Here is what I have found <https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/reverse+of+cd+command>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have `cd -` natively (cmd, powershell) on windows.

You can either:

1) Have cygwin on your windows and use bash

2) Have Linux subsystem on your Win 10 and use bash there.

3) use `pushd` on the directory you want to save.  Then change somewhere you want.
To return back you just `popd`

## **First and Second Edit**

There is a my own workaround with Powershell (licence MIT, but have my SO 'nick' there).

It will work the following way:

```
`cd` ... to list stack of saved directories
`cd -` ... return to previous directory (putting another `cd -` goes further to the history)
`cd +` ... add current directory to the top of the stack
`cd <path>` ... changes the path and puts the previous to the stack
```

You could put the following code in your `Profile.ps1`

```
# to remove default alias
Remove-Item Alias:cd -force

# create a new named stack at your ~ dir
Push-Location ~ -StackName 'RememberPaths'

# create a new cd with stack
function cd_with_stack { 
<#
.SYNOPSIS
   Change directory (cd)replacement 
.DESCRIPTION
   Remembers history when changing directories.  When directory is changed then it is added to the stack
   User can return to the history;
   User can force manually adding a directory;
   User can view the whole history stack.

.PARAMETER parameter
   Can be - ... to return to the historical directory
   Can be + ... to add current directory to the stack
   Can be empty ... to view the whole stack
   Can contain directory path to change it
.EXAMPLE
   PS c:\users > cd -
   PS c:\ >

   PS C:\t> cd

   Path
   ----
   C:\t
   C:\users\admin
   C:\users
   C:\Users\tukan
.NOTES
Author:
Tukan @StackOverflow 

Version Info:
1.0 - 27/02/2018
    - Initial release 
.LINK 
    http://www.ceq.cz
#>



    param ([String]$parameter)

    switch ($parameter) {
       '-' {
               If ((Get-location -StackName 'RememberPaths').Count -gt 1) {
                   popd -StackName 'RememberPaths'
               } Else { 
                   # do not empty stack, always keep the first item on stack
                   Set-Location -Path ((Get-location -StackName 'RememberPaths').Peek().ToString())
               }
               break
           }
       '+' { 
                If ((Get-location -StackName 'RememberPaths').Peek().ToString() -ne (Convert-Path .)) {
                    pushd -StackName 'RememberPaths'
                }
                # Else -> no path storing to stack
                break
           }
       ''  { get-location -StackName 'RememberPaths'; break }
        default { 
                     If (Test-Path -Path $parameter) {
                           If ((Get-location -StackName 'RememberPaths').Peek().ToString() -eq (Convert-Path .)) {
                               Set-Location -Path $parameter
                           } Else {
                               pushd -Path $parameter -StackName 'RememberPaths'
                           }
                     } Else {
                           Write-Warning "Probably wrong path $parameter"
                     }
                    break
                }
    }
}

# setting new alias for cd
set-alias cd cd_with_stack
```

Details about commands:

Based on that comment below the question I'm adding this information.  Which shows only a partial information.

With the `pushd` and `popd` it is important to differentiate when using **cmd** shell or **powershell**

**In powershell**  - these two commands are **aliases** to different commands

```
PS C:\Users> get-alias -name pushd

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Alias           pushd -> Push-Location

PS C:\Users> get-help pushd

NAME
    Push-Location

SYNTAX
    Push-Location [[-Path] <string>] [-PassThru] [-StackName <string>] [-UseTransaction]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Push-Location [-LiteralPath <string>] [-PassThru] [-StackName <string>] [-UseTransaction]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    pushd


REMARKS
    Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.
        -- To download and install Help files for the module that includes this cmdlet, use Update-Help.
        -- To view the Help topic for this cmdlet online, type: "Get-Help Push-Location -Online" or
           go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113370.


PS C:\Users> get-alias -name popd

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Alias           popd -> Pop-Location

PS C:\Users> get-help  popd

NAME
    Pop-Location

SYNTAX
    Pop-Location [-PassThru] [-StackName <string>] [-UseTransaction]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    popd


REMARKS
    Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.
        -- To download and install Help files for the module that includes this cmdlet, use Update-Help.
        -- To view the Help topic for this cmdlet online, type: "Get-Help Pop-Location -Online" or
           go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113369.
```

In **cmd.exe (or command.com)** the `pushd` and `popd` are **internal** commands of the interpreter:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pushd /?
Stores the current directory for use by the POPD command, then
changes to the specified directory.

PUSHD [path | ..]

  path        Specifies the directory to make the current directory.

If Command Extensions are enabled the PUSHD command accepts
network paths in addition to the normal drive letter and path.
If a network path is specified, PUSHD will create a temporary
drive letter that points to that specified network resource and
then change the current drive and directory, using the newly
defined drive letter.  Temporary drive letters are allocated from
Z: on down, using the first unused drive letter found.

C:\Windows\system32>pushd /?
Stores the current directory for use by the POPD command, then
changes to the specified directory.

PUSHD [path | ..]

  path        Specifies the directory to make the current directory.

If Command Extensions are enabled the PUSHD command accepts
network paths in addition to the normal drive letter and path.
If a network path is specified, PUSHD will create a temporary
drive letter that points to that specified network resource and
then change the current drive and directory, using the newly
defined drive letter.  Temporary drive letters are allocated from
Z: on down, using the first unused drive letter found.
```

Answer (score 3):

It's true that you do not have `cd-` natively on Windows.
BUT you can use `cd..` to go back one directory.

```
C:\Users\Acer\cd..
```

Will send you back to `C:Users\` directory.

I know this answer is late, but again may be helpful for someone else.
Thanks!

Comment: If you're showing the command, I think you meant to use a `>` as in `C:\Users\Acer>cd..` But the Question asked to go back to the previous directory, not the parent directory.